# Is there a feature in spark that skips a left join in case when the field that gets added by left join is not required

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose we have a table A and we are doing a left join with a large Table B (to fetch field colB)
Then the output is again left joined with a large table C (to fetch field colC) and finally we left join this with a table D (to fetch field colD)

So above 3 left-joins help to create a final dataset that is shared by multiple consumers.

As a consumer of this code , i do a select colA's , colD from the final dataset (I don't need colB and colC )

**Is there a feature which will skip 2 joins with B & C (since colB and colC are not required downstream in my case)**

FYI :

- I don't want to change the implementation(i.e. 3 joins) since this
  method is used by mutiple teams.
- I dont want to create my own implementation (avoid code duplication ,
  and to stay up to date with the logic that is used across the teams )

PS for clarity: 
B,C,D are huge dim tables
A is a fact table (relatively smaller than B,C,D)

Comment: unclear if a persisted dataset or a piece of shared code.

Comment: Dataset A,B,C,D : are hive tables I am reading from HDFS

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that this is possible without changing the original code. The reason is that even if the final result does not contain columns from tables B and C, the result might still depend on which tables were part of the join chain.

An example: lets assume we have this data and we want to join the four tables with the id column.

```
Table A     Table B     Table C     Table D
+---+----+  +---+----+  +---+----+  +---+----+
| id|colA|  | id|colB|  | id|colC|  | id|colD|
+---+----+  +---+----+  +---+----+  +---+----+
|  1|  A1|  |  1|  B1|  |  1|  C1|  |  1|  D1|
|  2|  A2|  |  2|  B2|  |  2|  C2|  |  2|  D2|
+---+----+  +---+----+  |  2| C2b|  +---+----+
                        +---+----+
```

The important point to note is that the table C contains a duplicate value in the join column.

If the four tables are joined with a left join and the columns A and D are selected, the result would be

```
+---+----+----+----+----+     +---+----+----+
| id|colA|colB|colC|colD|     | id|colA|colD|
+---+----+----+----+----+     +---+----+----+
|  1|  A1|  B1|  C1|  D1| ==> |  1|  A1|  D1|
|  2|  A2|  B2| C2b|  D2|     |  2|  A2|  D2|
|  2|  A2|  B2|  C2|  D2|     |  2|  A2|  D2|
+---+----+----+----+----+     +---+----+----+
```

On the other hand, if only the tables A and D are joined directly without tables B and C, the result would be

```
+---+----+----+
| id|colA|colD|
+---+----+----+
|  1|  A1|  D1|
|  2|  A2|  D2|
+---+----+----+
```

So even if the final result contains no columns from tables B and C, the result is different if you join A->D or A->B->C->D. So the Spark code cannot skip the joins of the tables B and C.

The good news: if you go the way A->B->C->D and exclude the columns from tables B and C, Spark will only process the *join column(s)* of tables B and C and skips (for example during a shuffle) all other columns. So at least the amount of data that is processed will be lower when not selecting columns from tables B and C.

Comment: while doing a left join we deduplicate the large tables (B,C,D) , so the output will be same (if we exclude B &C)

Comment: but how would the Spark engine be able to know that?

Comment: we can pass a flag (If spark supports this) saying that spark can ignore those left joins which are fruitless. (fruitless here means : joins that yield fields that are not of my use)

looks like we will need to handle this by code .

Comment: I am not aware that Spark supports that kind of flags